# How I know is the link sent to my wallet for Solana JUPITER airdrop is not Scan?

Tags: airdrop

How I know if the link sent to my wallet for Solana Jupiter airdrop is not Scan?

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** trust any links that are sent to you as NFTs!

You should only trust links shared by the official communications channel, in the case of Jupiter a good source would be [their Twitter](https://twitter.com/JupiterExchange).

For the ongoing `$WEN` airdrop, [this is the official website](https://lfg.jup.ag/wen), you can see the domain `jup.ag` matches the one in their Twitter profile.

Comment: Thank you  for your answers 